# Need a quick CSS tip?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to accomplish something. I'm building a responsive website, and I've run into an interesting issue.

I have a #wrapper, it's background is #FFF. Inside that for display needs i placed a header with some content and a body and each has a different background so it's easy to see what's positioned where.

For my Wrapper, i gave it a width of 100% so it expands and contracts with the browser window. But limited it's max-width to 750px as i dont want the website to be wider than that.

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;
margin:20px auto;
padding:0px 20px;
width:100%;
max-width:750px;
background:#FFF;
}
```

Notice i placed a padding of 0px 20px on it. This is where my issue comes in. When you re-size the browser window the wrapper does contract along with it, but for some reason it disregards the padding on the right. I want to make sure that does NOT happen, because no matter the browser window size I want 20 pixel space on left & right sides.

Any ideas, hints, lessons :) ? http://jsfiddle.net/wuJ9H/

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you put the padding after the width within your wrapper css?

Comment: @dannymcc: Why don't you try it and find out? CSS attributes are order-agnostic.

Comment: Same issue. Nothing changes.

Comment: I'm playing with it now. I was under the impression the lowest CSS attribute overwrote higher ones. Not sure where I got that from!

Comment: @dannymcc That's true, but only for the same properties. Distinct properties are applied the same regardless of position in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `box-sizing:border-box` fixed it for me (Chrome 26, FF 19, IE9/10). This causes padding to be included in the width calculation.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wuJ9H/3/

```
#wrapper {

    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:0px 20px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:750px;
    background:#FFF;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### Why does it work?

> When you re-size the browser window the wrapper does contract along
>   with it, but for some reason it disregards the padding on the right.

To be clear, your original version didn't just hide the right padded area. It hid the right padded region + 20px, namely, the width of the left padded area. This is because you told the box the be 100% wide *plus* any padding or borders.

Thus, your box was 100% + 40px wide.

Adding `box-sizing: border-box` instructs the browser to include padding and borders in the width calculation. It's very handy for percentage-based values.

- [The `box-sizing` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Interesting, too bad it seems to fail in FireFox.

Comment: @ipxel - good catch, added `-moz-` prefix and it works. Forgot it's still needed in FF.

Comment: Note that `box-sizing` isn't supported in IE7, see my answer for an alternative for IE7.

Comment: Yes, I +1'd you for the IE7 alternate.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `box-sizing:border-box` to `#wrapper` then the padding will be included in the `width`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YN7b9/1/)

```
#wrapper {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

You may want to make `max-width:790px` now for it to appear the same when the window is wide.

### Support

`box-sizing` is not supported in IE7 and below [Reference](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing). If you want to support IE7 then you will need to place an inner wrapper inside `#wrapper`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7Pft/)

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:750px;
}
#inner {
    padding:0px 20px;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply removing the width should maintain the expanding functionality while fixing your issue:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:0px 20px;
    max-width:750px;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wuJ9H/2/

Comment: Make sure to mark a solution for this question so others can find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the padding in your size definitions. Add `box-sizing:border-box` to the wrapper element.